# background images not displaying

Tags: html, css, web-services, web, frontend

My file is setup like this:
main folder
index.html
css
image(folder)

and I've tried

```
background-image: url("../images/vegies.jpg") no-repeat;
                      ("images/vegies.jpg") no-repeat;
                      ('../images/vegies.jpg') no-repeat;
```

please, can anyone help me  ?

Comment: semicolon ends the declaration of style , please check your semicolon on first line

Comment: It's not really clear how your files are structured, could you please clearly define what folder is inside what?

Comment: still not working

Comment: I have the main folder, lets call it FOOD, then food contains index.html, style.css then another folder containing all my images called 'images' which has the vegies.jpg image

Comment: Have you tried "./images/...." i.e. one dot at the start, not 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your files are like:

- Food/

  - index.html
  - style.css
  - images/veggies.jpg

If you are inside style.css and you want to reach the pic, the path is `./images/veggies.jpg`

If you type `../` your path goes one folder outside, if you start with `./` you start from the same folder you are.